# Unbiased estimator with conditional expectation.

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Suppose that $X$ has a binomial distribution with parameter $N=1$ and $p=1/2$. Y, which is independent of $X$, has a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance 1. Consider the estimator $\mu$ of the form $W_1 = Y + 2X -1$. (Please see my work after parenthesis.)

(a.) Is $W_1$ unbiased? (Yes, because $E(W_1) = E(Y) + 2E(X) - 1 = \mu$)

(b.) What is the variance of $W_1$? ($Var(W_1)=Var(Y)+4Var(X)=1 + 4p(1-p)$)

(c.) Consider the estimator $W_2 = E[W_1|Y]$. Is $W_2$ unbiased? How does its variance compare to that of $W_1$? (I am not sure how to deal with conditional expectation here.)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Might want to look at Rao-Blackwell Theorem.

Comment: When you condition the expected value of an r.v. on the variable itself, the expected value becomes equal to the r.v.

Answer (score 0):

$W_2 = E(Y\lvert Y) + 2E(X\lvert Y) - E(1\lvert Y) = Y + 2E[X] -1 = Y$ so $W_2$ is unbiased and its variance is equal to 1.